# Keep Ubuntu 18.04 running but locked with password

Tags: passwords, ubuntu-18.04

I am performing long-running Matlab code on Ubuntu 18.04. Can I prevent other users from interrupting by requiring a password, but keep the operation running, while analyses are being made on the computer?

When I'm not at the computer, I don't want anyone else to tamper with the computer. but Matlab should keep working.

Comment: **N.B.** Be sure to post a paper note on the PC, because no matter how you lock it, someone with physical access can simply hold the power button down to force shutdown, if they think the machine is "stuck" (unresponsive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has a Lock Screen function. Top right icon (Lock Screen, Power Off, Restart, etc.).  Screen shot below.

Start your process.

Lock the screen.

Process continues running and then use your Ubuntu User Password to unlock. Make sure you have this.

I have tested this and it works.

@DrMoishe Pippik makes a good point to post a note on the computer that it is running so that someone does not accidentally force it off with the power button.

.

[image: Ubuntu Lock Screen]

Comment: Thank you so much John